# Submit a form on close tab/window event in jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to submit the form while closing the tab or window, the below code is not working

```
jQ(window).unbind('beforeunload', function() { 
                $("#submitBtn").click();
});
```

This is not working while closing the tab

Please provide help

Thank

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not a reliable way to bind, try this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {//code};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try native js

```
Window.onunload =    function(){
 // to do
}

Window.onbeforeunload = function(){
 // to do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `bind` instead of `unbind`.

```
jQ(window).bind('beforeunload', function() { 
                $("#submitBtn").click();
});
```

You can also directly submit the form if you select it.

```
jQ(window).bind('beforeunload', function() { 
                $("#myForm").submit();
});
```